# How to save current date and time to database using java?

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, datetime

I am using the following code to get the current date and time, but the output is not what I am expecting and I cant save it into database.

Output >> current: Tue Mar 05 09:58:26 EST 2013

Expected output >> current: 2013-03-05 9:58:26

```
 .....{  
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            System.out.println("current: " +parseFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)));
            return parseFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConstructionModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return date;
     }
        ......

        ps.setDate(....) <<< failed
```

Database

```
 name   type
 mydate Date
```

Comment: Why you are using client PC time instead of database server time?Using `CURRENT_TIME` or `NOW` SQL function is better for many reasons including that all data is based one , server system clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use sql timestamp for saving to the database. Convert your java.util.Date to [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

```
ps.setTimestamp(new java.sql.Timestamp(myDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: That wouldn't save the time part of the date.

Comment: I did it but it gives error which says, no suitable method found for setTimestamp(int,Date) method PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(int,Timestamp,Calendar) is not applicable method (int,Timestamp) is not applicable ....

Comment: @Daniel: You need to create a new Timestamp with your date, as in the example.

Comment: @Daniel: There are 2 different Timestamp. Are you using the one in the java.sql package? Note that your IDE may have imported java.security.Timestamp, that is a different one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to parse before formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date date = new Date();

String frmtdDate = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("frmtdDate: " + frmtdDate);
```

However, if you are trying to fit the date into some DB statement, you should not do it in the form of text, instead use one of the JDBC setters that utilize `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: @Daniel: You'll need to set it as Timestamp, to save the date and time. See my answer.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int, java.sql.Date)

Comment: @IgorRodriguez, with most JDBC APIs I know of, it can  be done as a Date, does not have to be a Timestamp

Comment: I changed it to your code and used the setTimestamp but gives me an error.

Comment: @foampile: If I don't have bad memory, I had problems with Date with some in-memory database. That's the reason I prefer now to use timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

`format` takes a `Date` and returns a formatted `String`. `parse` takes a formatted `String` and returns a `Date` object. When you do `parseFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date))` you are converting `Date` to `String` and to `Date` again. The value that is printed is the default representation provided by `Date.toString()` instead of the formatted string.

```
       System.out.println("current: " +dateFormat.format(date));
```