# in java, how to convert String to Date object "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"

Tags: java

i want to convert `String "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" (for ex,2015-04-13T10:00:00)` into date object with the same `format(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm)`. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Date objects don't *have* a format. You can parse using a particular format, but then when you want to convert the `Date` back into a `String`, you need to format with the same format.

Answer (score 1):

```
String dateString = "2015-04-13T10:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"); 
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

Now if you want to display the date in the same format, you can do the following

```
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date)); // Outputs "2015-04-13T10:00"
```

Comment: Its giving the output as "Mon Apr 13 10:00:00 IST 2015"

Comment: You probably did the following `System.out.println(date.toString());` , @Jon Skeet comment explains why it is outputting in that format.

Comment: @santro I edited my answer in order to show how to print the date like you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot  HyperZ.

Comment: i want to update this format(datetime) in mysql db. how to achieve this.

Comment: @santro Note that this (new) question is in fact off topic here. However, this should help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212832/how-to-save-current-date-and-time-to-database-using-java

Comment: @ HyperZ, Thanks a lot for your help.